# How do you solve $3^{x^2}=9^{4^x}+6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How do you solve
$$3^{x^2}=9^{4^x}+6\ ?$$
It seems really tough for me to find the value of $x$. What is the easy way to solve this kind of equations?

Comment: "this kind of equations" is very hard to solve for real values of $x$ (even determining the number of solutions can be challenging).

Comment: It hasn't got reasonable solutions...There's a solution near $-1.34986$, but that's just via numerical methods.

Comment: If you have a quora account, you could just have a look: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-solve-3-x-2-9-4x-+6. It is a popular question.

Comment: @StubbornAtom  That's $9^{4x}$...very different.  Though it's a weird coincidence, perhaps the OP meant your version.

Comment: @lulu Yes I overlooked that.

Comment: yes..this one is different

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the factorization of non prime bases of powers:

$$3^{x^2}=(3^2)^{(2^2)^x}+6$$

This is

$$3^{x^2}=3^{2^{2x+1}}+6$$

Now, this equation can not be solved analitically. But we can use number theory to look for integer or rational solutions.

If $x$ is a positive integer, $3^{2^{2x+1}}$ is certainly a multiple of $9$, and $6$ is not. Therefore, $3^{x^2}$ is not a multiple of $9$. This means that $x$ must be $1$. But $x=1$ does not satisfy the equation.

It is easy to see that $x=0$ is not a solution.

If $x$ is a negative integer, LHS is integer, but RHS is irrational. So there is no integer solution.

If $x$ is not integer but $2x$ is integer, then the LHS is irrational but the RHS is rational.

[More advanced number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) allows to claim that if $x$ is rational and $2x$ is not integer, $3^{x^2}$ is algebraic and $3^{2^{2x+1}}$ is trascendental. Then, the equation has no rational solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar line of attack that ajotatxe suggested, but could not get all the bases of 3 on one side so that a logarithm could simiplify things down.

I think this equation, as far as getting a practical solution, must be solved using some kind of root-finding method, e.g. Newton's Method, regula falsi, or any number of other methods.